# Defining a constructor for ponyorm's Entities results in TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ponyorm

i just wanted to try out the pony orm mapper for a small personal web application.
Everything works fine except for defining a custom constructor for an entity.

In the following code i created a simple entity with a string field `name` and defined a constructor which does nothing but redirect the arguments to the parent constructor (in my real app i change some of the arguments bevor passing them to the parent constructor). After that i create one `User` and print its name.

```
from pony.orm import Database, Required, db_session, commit


db = Database("sqlite", ":memory:", create_db=True)


class User(db.Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    name = Required(str)


db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    u = User(name="Admin")
    commit()
    print(u, u.name)
```

The error message is `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` in the same line as the `super()`call.
It looks like the keyword arguments are sent to `object` instead of `db.Entity`.
When i remove the constructor everything works

So why doesn't it work. Shouldn't a constructor like the one in my example just always work (and do nothing of course)?
Is there something in ponyorm that prevents it from working or am i missing something here?

For completeness sake my entity definition actually looks like this

```
class User(db.Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "password" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("password is required")
        kwargs["password"] = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(kwargs["password"])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    name = Required(str)
    password = Required(str)
```

It produces the same results.

Also in the official documentation it says that method creation in entities is allowed at least. http://doc.ponyorm.com/entities.html#adding-custom-methods-to-entities .
But it doesn't say anything about constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until that moment the `Entity` class did not have the `__init__` method at all. For historical reasons, initialization of entity instance took place in the `__new__` method. Because of this, when you call `super(User, self).__init__` you actually call the `object.__init__` method. While in Python 2 the `object.__init__` method silently accepted any arguments, in Python 3 that method raises the error (the one that you've got) when you pass any argument to it.

After looking at your question we changed the initialization logic of entity instances and now we use `__init__` method in a traditional way. If you take the last version of PonyORM from GitHub your code should work fine. This change will be part of the next release PonyORM 0.6.2.

Thanks for pointing out to this!

Comment: Great. Now the error message actually makes sense to me. Were there any reasons (besides from "historical") why the initialization took place in the `__new__` method?

Comment: There are two situations when entity instance is created in memory: the one is when a user creates a new instance, and the other is when an object is loaded from the database. Pony uses IdentityMap pattern for its objects. This way Pony prevents duplicates: if an object was already loaded then the second attempt to load the same object does not create a duplicate object, but just return the previous one. The `__new__` method allows to control the object instantiation process and return previously existing object instead of creating a new one. Now Pony do the same without defining `__new__`.